# angularjs nvd3-line-chart set y2 axis

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use `nvd3-line-chart` angularjs directive.
My data is:

```
$scope.exampleData = [
  {
      "key": "Series 1",
      "values": [ [1, 2], [2, 10], [3, 6], [4, 15], [5, 8] ]
  },
  {
      "key": "Series 2",
      "values": [ [1, 5], [2, 30], [3, 8], [4, 11], [5, 4] ]
  },
  {
      "key": "Series 3",
      "values": [ [1, 2000], [2, 10000], [3, 600], [4, 1500], [5, 8000] ]
  }
]
```

Html:

```
nvd3-line-chart(
  data="exampleData"
  id="graph-Data-1"
  width="1170"
  height="494"
  showXAxis="true"
  showYAxis="true"
  tooltips="true"
  useInteractiveGuideline="true"
  showLegend="true"
  ng-if="exampleData"
)
```

How i can assign Y2 to Series 3 data? I found `line-plus-bar-chart` directive but how can i implement this via `nvd3-line-chart` directive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't use your data to render a secondary axis. It is out of the scope of the data itself.

The best thing you could do is to trick it yourself: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/using-multiple-axes-for-d3js-graph.html